# Android Studio: show compiler error immediately / not only on the right side

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, ide

By default Android Studio shows compiler errors by a red, horizontal line on the right side of the code editor. Is there any plugin to show it in the left side (where the line numbers are) or even better at the bottom in a separate view like in Visual Studio and all the other IDEs?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared some images showing what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is one plugin that shows you errors in the left side, **Error item line marker** from Chris Gamache , but I didnt find one plugin to show you errors at terminal like VS.

Comment: Thank you. The plugin however, didnt work for me when I tried in Android Studio with Kotlin code ):